# How to remove items in a sorted set using python in redis

Tags: python, redis

How to I removed items in a sorted set greater than a value using python?

```
key = 'foo'
pipe = redis_master_conn.pipeline()
pipe.zadd(key,1,'a')
pipe.zadd(key,2,'b')
pipe.zadd(key,3,'c')
pipe.zadd(key,4,'d')
pipe.zadd(key,5,'e')
pipe.execute()

redis_master_conn.zremrangebyscore('foo',4,'+inf')
```

Below is the result

```
zrange foo 0 -1
1) "a"
2) "b"
3) "c"
4) "d"
5) "e"
```

The above did not work.  Nothing was removed

Comment: Can you include only Python code which is used?